# Is there a way to get the computed values of long formulae from XLSX file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx, pycel

I am trying to read many XLSX files, and I don't care about the function, I just need the value it returns. The file is not and will not be modified, so getting the cache values in those cells is also fine for me.

I have read and tried many solutions on StackOverflow but none of them work:

1. Some people say that pandas will read the value instead of formulae by default

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

I have tried it, but all cells with a formula in my Dataframe become `nan`

2. I tried with openpyxl:

With `data_only = True`, all the cell is also `nan`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = f, data_only = True)
```

2.1. I also tried with `data_only = False`, and then compute the value with `pycel`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = f, data_only = True)
```

```
from pycel.excelcompiler import ExcelCompiler
cal = ExcelCompiler(f)
cal.evaluate(f"{name}!{cell}")
```

This one is nearly good enough for me since it can compute simple formula such as `=IFERROR(E98/E78,"-")`, but there's some complicated one such as `=(SUM(AC38:AD38)/BH45)/(SUM(Q38:R38)/BD45)-1` I got a recursion error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
Eval: vlookup(_C_("Key Metrics!C80"), _R_("YipitData Metrics (1P)!C8:AAT27"), match(_C_("Key Metrics!D7"), _R_("YipitData Metrics (1P)!C5:AAT5"), 0), 0) / vlookup("Implied JD Mall 1P GMV Net/Gross & Coverage Ratio", _R_("Historical Accuracy!B60:ADD70"), match(_C_("Key Metrics!D7"), _R_("Historical Accuracy!B58:ADD58"), 0), 0)
```

The full log of this error is really long, but all of them are `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` and then another `RecurssionError`

2.2. Another attempt to compute the formula again with `formulas` but when I run this line of code:
`model = formulas.ExcelModel().load(filename).finish()`
I got the error:

```
Failed DISPATCHING 'CHAR' due to:
  NotImplementedError()
```

The log is much longer but I cannot include it all as StackOverflow says my post looks like a spam

3. I also tried with xlrd, but the result is the same as pandas, all those cells become nan.

Read the file by `openpyxl` with the flag `data_only=False` and then calculate the value again with `pycel` is my best shot now, but it is not enough as it cannot read such long formula like I quoted above. Is there any change or another library that can fix my issue? Thank you!

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: If the file isn't going to change, maybe export it to .csv and work with that?